# how can I group by ID and count only values with 5 on mysql?

Tags: mysql, model, nested

I have this mysql query that gives me all child elements of when ID = 5 and now I want to group the result by ID and count how many elements = 5 do I have per level

```
`SELECT t1.ID, t1.name,
t1.ID as level1, t1.introID as i1, 
t2.ID as level2, t2.introID as i2,
t3.ID as level3, t3.introID as i3,
t4.ID as level4, t4.introID as i4,
t5.ID as level5, t5.introID as i5,
t6.ID as level6, t6.introID as i6,
t7.ID as level7, t7.introID as i7,
t8.ID as level8, t8.introID as i8,
t9.ID as level9, t9.introID as i9, 
t10.ID as level10, t10.introID as i10
FROM members AS t1
LEFT JOIN members AS t2 ON t2.parentID = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t3 ON t3.parentID = t2.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t4 ON t4.parentID = t3.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t5 ON t5.parentID = t4.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t6 ON t6.parentID = t5.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t7 ON t7.parentID = t6.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t8 ON t8.parentID = t7.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t9 ON t9.parentID = t8.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t10 ON t10.parentID = t9.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t11 ON t11.parentID = t10.ID
WHERE t1.ID = 5
group by t2.id, t3.id, t4.id, t5.id, t6.id, t7.id, t8.id, t9.id, t10.id`
```

this produces this result:

```
    ID  NAME        LEVEL1      I1   LEVEL2 I2  LEVEL3  I3  LEVEL4  I4
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       14  0   41      0   122     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       14  0   41      0   123     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       14  0   41      0   124     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       14  0   42      0   125     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       14  0   42      0   126     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       14  0   42      0   127     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       14  0   43      0   128     5                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       14  0   43      0   129     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       14  0   43      0   130     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       15  0   44      0   131     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       15  0   44      0   132     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       15  0   44      0   133     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       15  0   45      5   134     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       15  0   45      5   135     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       15  0   45      5   136     5                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       15  0   46      0   137     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       15  0   46      0   138     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       15  0   46      0   139     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   47      0   140     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   47      0   141     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   47      0   142     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   48      0   143     5                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   48      0   144     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   48      0   145     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   49      5   146     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   49      5   147     0                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   49      5   148     0
```

I want to get the count of elemtents equal to 5 in each i column and group the results per id and then remove the ID from select , the final criteria to count how many elements = 5 are in each i column is this, in i1 and i2 there are no elements, but in i3 and i4 we can see in LEVEL3 column the ID of the child element that has a introID = 5 in this case we can see repetly elements 45 and 49 with values on i4 = 5, but when counting it could lead to get 6 when the reality is that has to be 2 on column I3

```
    ID  NAME        LEVEL1      I1   LEVEL2 I2  LEVEL3  I3  LEVEL4  I4
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       14  0   43      0   128     5                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       15  0   45      5   
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       15  0   45      5   
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       15  0   45      5   136     5                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   48      0   143     5                                               
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   48      0   
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   48      0   
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   49      5   
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   49      5   
    5   Vina Malik  5           0       16  0   49      5
```

so the final result has to be this:

```
    ID  NAME        I1   I2  I3  I4
    5   Vina Malik  0    0   2   3
```

can anyone help me to group and count everything to get the required results?
thanks

Comment: OMG, your design is... not very good (saying it *very* politely). Please consider refactoring it as [nested set model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

Comment: ok, I'm using the adjacency list model, I'm not sure how to implement the nested set model... :(

Comment: Also I cannot implement the nested set model because I would need to have left and right values and I cannot change the database model, that model is something I canNOT modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll echo the comment above that you should probably consider redesigning your database schema.

However - based on the schema that you have, I believe this query will get you what you want:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.name,
COUNT(distinct IF(t1.introID = 5, t1.ID, NULL)) AS I1,
COUNT(distinct IF(t2.introID = 5, t2.ID, NULL)) AS I2,
COUNT(distinct IF(t3.introID = 5, t3.ID, NULL)) AS I3,
COUNT(distinct IF(t4.introID = 5, t4.ID, NULL)) AS I4,
COUNT(distinct IF(t5.introID = 5, t5.ID, NULL)) AS I5,
COUNT(distinct IF(t6.introID = 5, t6.ID, NULL)) AS I6,
COUNT(distinct IF(t7.introID = 5, t7.ID, NULL)) AS I7,
COUNT(distinct IF(t8.introID = 5, t8.ID, NULL)) AS I8,
COUNT(distinct IF(t9.introID = 5, t9.ID, NULL)) AS I9,
COUNT(distinct IF(t10.introID = 5, t10.ID, NULL)) AS I10
FROM members AS t1
LEFT JOIN members AS t2 ON t2.parentID = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t3 ON t3.parentID = t2.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t4 ON t4.parentID = t3.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t5 ON t5.parentID = t4.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t6 ON t6.parentID = t5.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t7 ON t7.parentID = t6.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t8 ON t8.parentID = t7.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t9 ON t9.parentID = t8.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t10 ON t10.parentID = t9.ID
LEFT JOIN members AS t11 ON t11.parentID = t10.ID
WHERE t1.ID = 5
group by t1.id;
```

You can view an SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e109/5

Comment: OMG this is it!! thanks a lot you are awesome, it worked like a charm, and sadly this database model is not something I can modify, I huge organization uses this model and well, I'm just dealing with it... thanks a lot...